# Как отключить полосы прокрутки у FlowDocumentScrollViewer в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как отключить полосы прокрутки у FlowDocumentScrollViewer в WPF?

Comment: HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" или "Hidden"